# Scala Cast List of Any to list of Int

Tags: scala, int, double, any

Given a List of Any:

```
val l = List(2.9940714E7, 2.9931662E7, 2.993162E7, 2.9931625E7, 2.9930708E7, 2.9930708E7, 2.9931477E7)
```

I need to cast each item to Int.

**Works:**

```
l(1).asInstanceOf[Double].toInt
```

**Not:**

```
l.foreach{_.asInstanceOf[Double].toInt}
> java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
```

**If**

```
l.foreach{_.asInstanceOf[String].toDouble.toInt}
> java.lang.Double cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I'm new to Scala. Please tell me what I'm missing.
Why I can cast one item from list, but can't do this via iterator?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if a `String` somehow ended up in your `List` `l`.

Given a list that is structured like this (with mixed integers, `Double`s, and `String`s):

```
val l = List[Any](2.9940714E7, 2.9931625E7, "2.345E8", 345563)
```

You can convert it to list of integers as follows:

```
val lAsInts = l.map {
  case i: Int => i
  case d: Double => d.toInt
  case s: String => s.toDouble.toInt
}

println(lAsInts)
```

This works for `Double`s, `Int`s and `String`s. If it still crashes with some exceptions during the cast, then you can add more cases. You can, of course, do the same in a `foreach` if you want, but in this case it wouldn't do anything, because you don't *do* anything in the body of `foreach` except casting. This has no useful side-effects (e.g. it prints nothing).

Another option would be:

```
lAsInts = l.map{_.toString.toDouble.toInt}
```

This is in a way even more forgiving to all kind of weird input, at least as long as all values are "numeric" in some sense.

However, this is definitely code-smell: how did you get a list with such a wild mix of values to begin with?

Comment: It's a very long story.
I have some json with numerous properties in different types. 
I've extracted that data from Redis, parsed with scala.util.parsing.json._
it returned Map[String, Any] but it turned values with type String like "29940714" to Any 2.9940714E7 after parsing.
And I afterwards I map obtained Map with case class to have ojects with necessary data then filter by some properties. 

Anyways _.toString.toDouble.toInt worked fine. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

Your given `List` is of type `Double`. You can use simply `map` operation to convert it to `Int` type. try following code,

```
val l: List[Double] = List(2.9940714E7, 2.9931662E7, 2.993162E7, 2.9931625E7, 2.9930708E7, 2.9930708E7, 2.9931477E7)

//simply map the list and use toInt
val intLst: List[Int] = l.map(_.toInt)

print(intLst)

//output
//List(29940714, 29931662, 29931620, 29931625, 29930708, 29930708, 29931477)
```

But suppose you have same `List` as `List[Any]` instead then you can use following to convert it to `Int`.

```
val l: List[Any] = List(2.9940714E7, 2.9931662E7, 2.993162E7, 2.9931625E7, 2.9930708E7, 2.9930708E7, 2.9931477E7)

val intLst: List[Int] = l.map(_.asInstanceOf[Double].toInt)
```

It will give same output as above.